# Does jQuery uses states?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a hard time finding a good yet simple article on the 'behind the scenes' of jQuery. I know this is not simple though.

But does jQuery actually uses cycles and states like React does ? If not, what is it, in simple words ?

What is happening when jQuery does that ?

```
$('.netreviews_stats_stars_big').css('opacity', '0.2');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "states"? You mean, like, a state machine?

Comment: I mean like a React app. It has an initial state and then that state gets modified. To be honest I have difficulties with the concept even in React, I just use them...

Comment: Why do you ask about jQuery when the actual task is to change the opacity with react?

Comment: @Andreas I think I am pretty clear, I want to know what happens in jQuery for it to be able to modify the DOM.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: This is what jQuery does: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.x-stable/src/css.js#L469

Comment: You probably meant "as React uses Redux". No, jQuery is just a library, not a framework. What you do with vanilla JS, you just have some short-hand less boilerplate code when you use jQuery. In your example, just DOM element has changed its CSS. No variables in memory were hurt in the process.

Comment: But React doesn't need Redux in order to use states but yeah, I get it, I was being mistaken I believe.

Comment: @Andreas now that is interesting ;)

Comment: That's [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @DevMoutarde True, Redux is optional for React (or any other framework for that matter). Now I am mistaken, I'm sorry. I'm not expert in React (watched few tutorials). I know Vue uses state management though, they call it a "store".

Comment: Oh yeah, I've seen this term in Redux ahah, probably something in common

Answer (score 1):

The DOM manipulation parts of jQuery do direct DOM manipulation. It doesn't take a data-driven approach like React so the idea of state in the React sense is meaningless.